# is there a buefy equivalent package for react?

Tags: reactjs, bulma, joi, formik, buefy

I was wondering if there is an npm package like [buefy](https://buefy.org/) for react, buefy is built for vue and works with bulma css. I have already found [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) and am doing some validation with joi, but I was just wondering if there is anything like buefy that uses bulma for react forms!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bloomer](https://bloomer.js.org/#/) and [bulma-react-components](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components) provides react components for Bulma. You can use Formik with any of them.

Comment: you can just import bulma and use it in react without all this with className, i don’t want formik i wanted something else if available

Comment: Bloomer was pretty interesting, thanks for that though.